# how to hide button depending on model value?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following logic:

```
if (Model != null && Model.StatusMessage != "New Override")
{
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Delete" >Delete</button>
}
```

and want to show 2 buttons in a row (button Save and button Delete).

However, when I add `table` tags  and place Save button into first `td` and logic above for Delete button into second `td` in same `tr`, logic stops working - it is not recognizable as code; and is considered to be just a text on a screen.

How can I have 2 buttons in one horizontal row; and show Delete button only if `Model.Status` tells me that record exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing in this in your View? if so, put `@if` instead of `if`. I assume your code is something like below...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
     @if(){
       <td></td>
     }
  </tr>
</table>
```

- put your save button in the first `td`
- `@if` is where your logic should go and if the condition is met, print another `td` for Delete button, otherwise do nothing

If you need more help, please post the code how you construct the table. Thanks.

Comment: You might like this article, which introduces the Razor syntax (which is what you're using) and contains some great examples and explanations. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple way using css and inline if to hide/show the button:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="Command" value="Delete" style="display:@(Model.StatusMessage != "New Override"?"block":"none")">Delete</button>
```

Using the display block/none style will also stop the button from taking up real estate if it is hidden.